# How to logon to X Window through a daemon on Fedora 16

Tags: java, authentication, x11, kde-plasma, fedora16

I work on a distributed system with a central control station.  On this central control
station we have software which will connect to any number of remote computers running Fedora 16 and a specialized SystemD daemon.  Once connected, the control station sends messages to these daemons in order to launch various GUI systems used for user interaction with the central control station.

Currently there is a huge downside to this, in that these remote computers require a particular user to be logged in before the GUI's can be brought up.  This user is the same user as is running the SystemD daemon.  If these remote computers are not logged in we receive the following java error:

`Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`

The daemon is written in Java (using the latest java 7) and uses the following code in order launch the 
GUIs:

```
String command = "java -Xmx2000M -cp ...{java classes etc to run}"
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split("\\s+"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.environment().put("DISPLAY", ":0.0");
try
{
  p = pb.start();
...
```

This is the correct DISPLAY variable when a user is properly logged on.
The daemon itself does not know that there is a Display because of when it starts, so we currently set the DISPLAY variable in the ProcessBuilder

Is there some way to properly connect/logon to the X11 Window Server either through java
or some other means through my daemons so that these systems do not need to be manually logged in to prior to running.

Currently, all these systems auto-loggin on start up to KDE as the appropriate user, but that isn't a very secure solution, and people have a tendency to log them out at random, stopping them from functioning as remote stations

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/inittab so X starts with OS. [Instructions](http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-auto-login-and-startx-without-a-display-manager-in-debian.html)

Create file .Xinitrc in your home directory. From it start your daemon, and if you need window manager start it too.

Comment: Unfortunately that works on a system using SysV but Fedora 16 only supports SystemD.

Comment: @Jordan Create service definition so start X without display manager (kdm, gdm. xdm) using startx as some user, than create .Xinitrc for that user.

Comment: These boxes are all already in run level 5 so the kdm is already running, just waiting for login.  I'm able to make this work if I'm in run level 3.  Is there some way to do this when kdm is already up?

Comment: You can remove service kdm from run level 5 or set default run level to 3.